# Building circuit for n-relays using flip flops, is this the best solution?

Tags: relay, flipflop, shift-register, latch

I'm trying to build a circuit for n relays, each relay should hold it's state (ie latched).

My first Idea was to use decoders, but clearly this was a bad option, since the state of the relays won't be maintained, basically there is no on/off toggle.

Finally I've found out that flip flops seem to be a good option, is this the correct path to follow? are there better and simple solutions? Let me know some topics to study.

Comment: How do you plan to provide input as to which relays should be active? Are you using programming logic such as a microcontroller?

Comment: @DanLaks Yes, using arduino, cleary I could have used the micro controler outputs to control directly each relay, but suppose I need to control more relays than what my outputs are available. I was trying to create a cuircuit that could cycle every relay and change or maintaine it's state.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is such a thing as a `Latching Relay`... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay But I can also see the appeal of figuring out the circuit design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specifically mention shift registers in your question, but you used the `shift-register` tag, so I assume you've considered the option. For simplicity and expand-ability, I would go that route. Most shift register ICs can be daisy-chained, so you can connect as many together as you want and theoretically control as many relays as you'd like.

The outputs of a shift register probably can't source (or sink) enough current to drive the relay coil directly, so you just need to add a transistor for each relay. It might look something like this using MOSFETs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiLAr3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Shift register ICs come in both push-pull outputs and open-drain outputs. The example circuit above assumes push-pull type outputs. Make sure you choose the right type for your circuit.

Comment: There are shift registers that can sink enough current to work with smallish relays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like an 8bit addressable latch. Have a look at the [SN74HC259](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc259.pdf)

[image]

You can control whether you want to use it as a latch with CLR =  1 and G = 0, and then feed in your address and your state. When you are not changing the states of the relays, you can put it into memory which is CLR = 1 and G = 1 and it will retain its previous values.

I've used this on a project in the past to control relays, but the I had a relay driver between the output of this IC and the relay itself.